# GlusterFS deployment on k8s cluster-- Readiness probe failed: /usr/local/bin/status-probe.sh

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

Setup: GlusterFS on k8s(AKS) cluster;

Having issue while glusterfs deploy using gk-deploy; below shared few error snippets please suggest workaround to get my deployment going- thanks in advance.

> Getting same error : Events: Type Reason Age From Message ---- ------
>   ---- ---- ------- Warning Unhealthy 8m44s (x459 over 3h45m) kubelet, aks-nodepool1-70391060-0 Readiness probe failed:
>   /usr/local/bin/status-probe.sh failed check: systemctl -q is-active
>   gluster-blockd.service Warning Unhealthy 4m2s (x462 over 3h46m)
>   kubelet, aks-nodepool1-70391060-0 Liveness probe failed:
>   /usr/local/bin/status-probe.sh failed check: systemctl -q is-active
>   gluster-blockd.service

When i inspect the pod with the glusterd status - it looks successful, what might be causing the reporting on readiness failed - any ideas / thoughts?

[glsuterd status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOZeA.png)

Comment: Have you checked gluster-blockd.service as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probe does not only check for the status of the `glusterd.service`. There are a few other things that are taken into account. The [`status-probe.sh` script is available from github](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-containers/blob/master/CentOS/status-probe.sh). The message

```
Liveness probe failed: /usr/local/bin/status-probe.sh failed check: systemctl -q is-active gluster-blockd.service
```

indicates that `gluster-blockd.service` is not running correctly. This can have different causes, you would need to inspect the `gluster-blockd.log` and `tcmu-runner.log` to find out what the problem is.

`gluster-blockd.service` is optional. If you do not need PersistentVolumes with type=block in your environment, you can disable the check.

In the specification of the daemonset, you can change the environment variable `GLUSTER_BLOCKD_STATUS_PROBE_ENABLE` and set the value to `"0"`.