# Readiness probe failed: /usr/local/bin/status-probe.sh failed check: systemctl -q is-active glusterd.service

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

I've followed the [setup guide](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/setup-guide.md) using the gk-deploy script

```
./gk-deploy.sh --admin-key xxxx --user-key xxx -v -g
```

This went fine. However, the deployed container fail with

> ```
> Readiness probe failed: /usr/local/bin/status-probe.sh failed check: systemctl -q is-active glusterd.service
> ```

The `glusterd.service` on the node is running:

```
$ systemctl status glusterd
● glusterd.service - GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/glusterd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-10-19 18:48:25 CEST; 1 day 17h ago
     Docs: man:glusterd(8)
  Process: 939 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/glusterd -p /var/run/glusterd.pid --log-level $LOG_LEVEL $GLUSTERD_
 Main PID: 955 (glusterd)
    Tasks: 10 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 30.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/glusterd.service
           └─955 /usr/sbin/glusterd -p /var/run/glusterd.pid --log-level INFO
....
```

`GLUSTER_BLOCKD_STATUS_PROBE_ENABLE` is set to "0"

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113811/glusterfs-deployment-on-k8s-cluster-readiness-probe-failed-usr-local-bin-sta), but does not really help me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with a simpler readiness probe to diagnose the problem. I would run the following script to make sure the service is indeed ok given this is the check that is failing.

```sh
systemctl -q is-active glusterd.service
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then 
  exit 0;
else 
  exit 1;
fi;
```

There is no point in checking the logs since systemctl will give us the necessary exit code.